# Convert for-loop and if condition to stream, filter, collect

Tags: java, filter, java-stream, collect

I am trying to convert this for loop and if condition to Java streams, filter and collect

```
final List<Optional<String>> students = listofstudents.get();

final List<String> finalist = new ArrayList<>(students.size());

for(int i=0; i<students.size(); i++) {
    if(students.get(i).isPresent()) {
        finalist.add(students.get(i).get());
    }
    else {
        finalist.add(null);
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
List<String>result = null;

students.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.isPresent())
        .map(e->result.add(e))
        .orElse(result.add(null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, this is completely wrong. I could not make it work as expected

can someone tell me how should i do it using stream, filter, collect?

Comment: Why do you want nulls in your list? Wouldn't you just want to remove the empty optionals? `List<String> result = students.stream().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).toList();` or `.collect(Collectors.toList());` if you are on an older version of Java.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the ternary conditional operator when mapping:

```
List<String> result = students.stream()
                              .map(op -> op.isPresent()? op.get() : null)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or as @Mark Rotteveel correctly commented:

```
students.stream().map(op -> op.orElse(null)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```